# pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(dataframe) in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

Why doesn't `pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(dataframe)` work in google colab?

Returns a type error.

```
TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'join_axes'
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have more context around this question, where does this appear in your code? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just try to upload any dataset and use the ProfileReport. The error will jump up. Why does it happen, how can i solve it?

Comment: You may try from sklearn import datasets, datasets.load_iris()

Answer (score 6):

Just use pandas-profiling version 2.7.1 and you are good to go.Run this command in the colab !pip install pandas-profiling==2.7.1

Answer (score 1):

Aishah Ismail's [post on Medium](https://medium.com/python-in-plain-english/how-to-use-pandas-profiling-on-google-colab-e34f34ff1c9f) may help you fix this issue.

Install the pandas-profiling package using pip.
`! pip install https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip`

Restart your kernel = Go to "Runtime" in the option menu and click "Reset All Runtimes"

Execute your code to create your dataframe and create the pandas profile.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
 
df = pd.read_excel('fileName.xlsx')
profile = ProfileReport(df)
profile.to_notebook_iframe()
```

You may need to pip install pandas-profiling if the import above does not work.
`!pip install pandas-profiling==2.7.1` Re-execute your code after the pip install.

When you try to display the profile do not use .to_widgets()--it isn't working in Colab.

*If the above doesn't work, I suggest switching to Jupyter Lab or Jupyter Notebook.  The pandas profile dashboard works well in the Jupyter environment.*

I hope this helps!  Pandas-Profiling a wonderful EDA tool--such a time saver.